# R split matrix by every column value

Tags: r, matrix, split, dataframe

I have a data frame in R like this(much more longer than this but I guess it summarizes):

```
label   id   value1   value2
p01     1      0        0
p02     2      1        3
p03     1      0        5
p04     2      2        4
p05     3      6        7
p06     1      0        8
```

And   would like to split them from every 1 value in id column. So in result I should have 3 sub matrices like:

```
p01     1      0        0
p02     2      1        3

p03     1      0        5
p04     2      2        4
p05     3      6        7

p06     1      0        8
```

How could I do that? I have tried:

```
result=split(xx,xx$id==1)
```

but it separates 1's and others.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can create the grouping variable by taking the cumulative sum of the logical vector(`df1$id==1`)

```
split(df1,cumsum(df1$id==1))
#$`1`
#  label id value1 value2
#1   p01  1      0      0
#2   p02  2      1      3

#$`2`
#  label id value1 value2
#3   p03  1      0      5
#4   p04  2      2      4
#5   p05  3      6      7

#$`3`
#  label id value1 value2
#6   p06  1      0      8
```